# Which programming language has this syntax?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

Which is this programming language?

```
$((1400+RANDOM%300))
```

I know it generates a random number between 1400 and 1699

Comment: Answer: many, but it means different things in each one of them.

Comment: I know it generates a random number between 1400 and 1699

Comment: Clearly Haskell with `-XTemplateHaskell` and `-XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with bash.

```
ole@servant:~$ echo $((1400+RANDOM%300))
1672
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html

Comment: @Shaz I thought "oh, that's wrong" at first too, but `RANDOM` is really a function.

Comment: @pst: it's a variable, but the value is recalculated (or rather generated) each time you read it. @Ole: Technically, it could be any ksh-derived shell: ksh, bash or zsh.

Comment: You got it? RANDOM%300 returns a random value less than 300. The encapsulation lets you use it as a variable. It's bash (and maybe other, what do I know).